# WebDriver HTMLUnit issues with Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, webdriver, htmlunit

I want to test a site using selenium webdriver (java), but that site contains ajax and HTMLUnit does not see the ajax content.

Is there a workaround?

Example:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
//login into your account
this.login(driver);
//click on edit Profile Link into an ajax-loaded tab
driver.findElement(By.id("editProfile")).click();
//Result: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: HTMLUnitDriver javascript support is pretty bad from my personal experience, and emulation is even worse. I stopped using it for regression tests since it introduces more bugs than what it can detect :(

Answer (score 5):

use Wait condition before interaction with element with must appear after ajax response.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 5);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_to_element")));
```

this makes webDriver to wait for your element during 5 secs. This question was asked earlier.

Comment: The issue is not focused on WebDriver itself, its focused on the HtmlUnitDriver with ajax...

Comment: WebDriver is an interface. HtmlUnitDriver and etc. are implementations of it. It's working by the same way. Don't worry about that.